# Just need help starting up for a program that transfer from c++/c to mips

Tags: java, c++, converters, mips

first of all I want to make it clear that's what  I am asking is for an assignment.

The idea was to make a program in c++ or java where the user enter a simple c code (A=B, a while loop, a for loop and array functions) and the output is the mips code (lw addi etc) we are free to use whatever registers doing so.

Surely I am not asking for the whole code. The problem is in my head I can only think of hardcoding the whole things inputting a string then cutting it into part and then run a hideous amount of if condition and or switch cases I think there must be a simpler way but I can't get my mind on it.

Comment: This sounds like a massive project.  Basically you're writing a compiler.

Comment: There's many steps to building a compiler. Also there's a lot of books on the subject. But to get you started, some keywords you can look up are "parsing", "lexing", "tokenization", "register allocation", "code emitter"

Comment: Sounds like you want to write a compiler. You are asking far too early in your discovery process to be able to make a good question. I recommend deleting this question for the time being  and sitting down with a pen and breaking down what you have to do into bite-sized chunks. Depending on how far you wish to go, a quick google for "Dragon Book" may help you out. But on second thought, maybe not. You likely need to start with something a little gentler on the soul. It's 2018. There have go to be more/better books on compiler design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Damn, whenever you get to studying compilers this will be crazy to look back to.

Anyway you are probably not in the level of building a C compiler from scratch.

So think of it this way, you need to have a set of instructions and yes you will have to go through the program string and transform the string into MIPS instructions.

The most naive way to do it and it might be what your teacher expects unless it is a compiler course, would be to parse the program text line by line as it is expected to be a simple program and as you said have a lot of conditions for each type of expression that you will evaluate.

A tip: Save for / while loops as a label as soon as you read them and from there you need to check where is the endpoint of it for the jump when necessary (completed for/while conditions etc)

Now if it is a compiler project. I'd strongly recommend you read into this book:

[Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321486811)

Because to build a real compiler you need to understand all the stages of a compiler and how does it work together... You would also need to know some Language Theory.

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer . It's not a compiler project (never studied compilers coding my whole life tbh) so I think you are right the teacher wants us to implement every case line by line the due date is next week so it's gonna be a long week

Comment: @AbdallahMohamed an alternative to massive `if`/`else` or `switch`/`case` block is a `std::map<std::string, std::function<something>>`. With this you have a bunch of functions, one function per token that does nothing but handle that one token, mapped to the tokens. Then when the parser gets a token, you do something like `while (token = getNextToken()) parserrmap[token](parameters);`. The beauty to this is if you later want to add another token, you make a function and add the token-function mapping to `parsemap`. No mess of conditional logic, just a single while loop.

Comment: This means you can easily write all of your commands one function at a time and exhaustively test each one by itself so you don't wind up with 20 commands implemented all at once and something like 200 bugs to sort out. Plus anything you learn from function one, you can apply to function 2 when you write function 2.